# Complexity of finding one vertex of a nonempty polytope

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Let $P$ be a polytope given by some half-space description: $P=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: Ax\leq b\}$ for some $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, b\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $m\geq n$. Assume that $x_0\in P$ for some given $x_0$ (in particular, $P\neq\emptyset$). What is the complexity of finding **one** (i.e., any) vertex of $P$?

Obviously, we can find a vertex in polynomial time by using Linear Programming, by optimizing over $P$ in an arbitrary direction, but I guess we can do better than that. For example, I think it might be possible to *shoot* from $x_0$ in an arbitrary direction until a face is hit (which can be done in $O(mn)$), and then proceed inductively within this face. To do this, I think we need to compute a basis for the affine hull of that face, which can be done in $O(n^3)$ operations using a QR decomposition (or a bit faster (in theory) if we use fast matrix multiplication, cf. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.02056.pdf)). Since we need $n$ iterations, that would be a $$O(n^2(m+n^2))$$ algorithm, can't we do better?

Comment: probably it's better to think of shooting at direction of increasing/decreasing a coordinate of $x_0$. So you compute the slacks at $x_0$ - here you need $O(mn)$: if one of them is 0, you got a facet to restrict to. Otherwise, pick an arbitrary coordinate $k$ of $x_0$, and form a univariate system of inequalities involving this coordinate as a variable. Find a vertex solution to it, this is a new value for the $k$-th coordinate of $x_0$, so that it lies on a facet. This can be done in $O(m)$ operations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a classical problem in Linear Programming - to start a simplex method, one must find a vertex.

This is so-called "Phase I" of the simplex method, and without doubt the best ways to do this have been researched a lot.
See e.g. what 
Brian Borchers [wrote in scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7616/how-to-start-the-simplex-method-from-a-feasible-internal-point/16268#16268), "How to start the Simplex method from a feasible internal point?"

---

It is not hard to show that $O(mn^2)$ operations suffice. Basically, it's some kind of extended Gauss elimination. Assume that we already have $k$ independent facets with $x_k$ on them, given by a triangularised matrix of the corresponding equations, and the remaining inequalities are also transformed so that the 1st $k\geq 0$ variables do not arise in them.

Now, fix the $k+2$-th, $k+3$-th,... $n$-th coordinate of $x$ to be as in $x_k$, obtaining a univariate system of inequalities -- $k+1$-th coordinate is the variable. It  specifies a finite range $[\tau,\tau']$. Set the $k+1$-th coordinate of $x_{k+1}$ to be equal to either $\tau$ or $\tau'$, and the $k+2$-th,... $n$-th coordinates of $x_{k+1}$ to be the same as in $x_k$.  Use the triangular system of equations to back-solve for $k$-th, $k-1$-th,...,1st coordinates of $x_{k+1}$. (This is all quick, needs $O(nm)$).

Now we have $x_{k+1}$, lying in a face of smaller dimension that $x_k$; at this point one has to triangularise the newly found equations; if the dimension of the face drops by $r$, one needs at most $O(rnm)$ operations. At this point we are ready to repeat the loop, with $k$ increased by $r$.

Comment: Hi Dima, yes,you' re right, this problem is related to Phase 1. However, I cannot accept your answer for 2 reasons: In my understanding, the typical (textbook) way to solve Phase 1 is to use simplex iterations, starting from a basic feasible solution for a modified problem. I am interested in complexity, so I would like to avoid the simplex...

Comment: I also get stuck around the same problem as [Dylan](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7616/how-to-start-the-simplex-method-from-a-feasible-internal-point/16258#comment12631_7620) Phase 1 adds slack variables and work with an LP in canonical form, for which a BFS is known, while I want a simple method that finds a vertex in the form $P=\{x:Ax\leq b\}$ that takes advantage of the knowledge of a point $x_0 \in P$

Comment: It seems that the approach proposed by [Rahul](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/16257/31696) in the same question is exactly what I suggested above, I would happily welcome any reference in some text book that describes that approach.

Comment: probably there is a reason that simplex is fast in Phase I, some kind of general position situation that makes pivoting fast.

Comment: see the edit for something that is probably close to optimal...

Comment: Would you be interested in taking a look at this problem of convex polytope containment https://mathoverflow.net/q/385579/32660?