# Confining a polytope to one side of an affine hyperplane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Judging whether one convex polytope is inside of another when both are expressed as a system of linear inequalities seems not to be an easy problem.
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198091/64809) on math.stackexchange.com claims the following proposition regarding a special case.

Using Farkas' lemma to show, a halfspace $\{x \mid a' x \leq b' \}$  contains the polytope $P= \{x |A x \leq b \}$ if and only if there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^m$ with  $\lambda \geq 0$ (understood component-wise) such that:
\begin{align*}
a' &= \lambda^T A \\
b' &\geq \lambda^T b
\end{align*}

It is easy to prove the sufficiency. I am able to show the necessity of $a' = \lambda^T A$ by Farkas' lemma, but not $b' \geq \lambda^T b$. I tried but failed to argue by contradiction. How does one prove that last inequality?

Comment: look at the dual polytope P* of P. Then your halfspace does not cut P iff it is contained in P*, more or less by definition of the dual polytope.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: I do not understand your comment. I just looked up the definition of a dual polytope. It seems to me that however this other polytope is configured, so long as it is not the complement of $P$, the iff does not seem to hold. What am I missing? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: P* contains the inequalities valid for P. Vertices of P* are facets of P, convex linear combinations of vertices of P* are, in general, less tight inequalities valid for P, what is unclear? Try this on a 4 gon in plane...

Comment: Meta question about the accepted answer to this question: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5084/unaccepting-an-answer-and-then-accepting-own-similar-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof that uses directly the [separating hyperplane theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), which states the following.

Given a matrix $A$ and column matrix $b$,
\begin{align}
Ax=b, &\text{ for some column matrix }x\ge0 \\
&\iff \\
y^TA\ge0 &\text{ for some column matrix }y \implies y^Tb\ge0
\end{align}

---

We put as follows the required proposition into the above form with the exception that the matrix is transposed. The premise of the proposition is
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
A & b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-xx_1 \\
x_1
\end{bmatrix}\ge 0  \\
&\iff \\
&\begin{cases} Ax\le b \implies a'^Tx\le b' \\
x_1\ge0 
\end{cases}
\\
&\implies \\
&\begin{bmatrix}a'^T &b'\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-xx_1 \\x_1 \end{bmatrix}\ge0
\end{align}

The conclusion of the proposition is
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}\lambda^T & \lambda_1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
A & b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a'^T & b'\end{bmatrix}, \text{ for some} \begin{bmatrix}\lambda^T & \lambda_1\end{bmatrix}\ge0 \\
&\iff \\
&\exists \lambda\ge0 \ni
\begin{cases}
\lambda^TA=a'^T \\ 
\lambda^Tb\le b'
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The premise and the conclusion are seen to be equivalent in view of the separating hyperplane theorem as stated above. We have now proved the desired proposition.

Comment: Can the down-voter explain why he down-votes? What is wrong with the proof?

Comment: you unaccepted [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/386258/14094) and accepted this one, without even mentioning the original accepted answer. The author of the originally accepted answer believes this is unfair, and posted [this question on Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5084/unaccepting-an-answer-and-then-accepting-own-similar-answer) (apparently without notifying you), and possibly downvoted this answer. While I don't believe downvoting was accurate (nor am I sure who downvoted your answer), I believe you should react to the meta post in some way.

Comment: @YCor: Thank you for alerting me to the Meta post related to this question. I have never used Meta part of mathoverflow. I will look into that item later, as I am occupied right now, and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

On can use Linear Programming (LP) duality.
Consider the LP problem
$$\beta':=\max \langle a',x\rangle : x\in P.\tag{P}$$
So $\beta'$ is minimal number s.t. $\langle a',x\rangle\leq\beta'$ for all $x\in P$.
Thus $\beta'\leq b'$, for $b'$ as in the question.

The [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program#Vector_formulations) of (P) is
$$
\beta^*:=\min \langle\lambda,b\rangle : \lambda\geq 0, \lambda^\top A=a'. \tag{D}
$$
So we see that (D) encodes all the possible $\lambda$ giving $\lambda^\top A=a'$.

[Strong duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program#Strong_duality) says that $\beta'=\beta^*$, i.e. there exists feasible $\lambda$ s.t.
$\langle \lambda, b\rangle=\beta'\leq b'$, as required.

Strong duality is not so easy to show, and it appears to be equivalent to the question asked. (Note that it is easier to show weak duality, which is $\beta^*\geq\beta'$, and this does not give the needed inequality).

Comment: +1. This is a great approach. I will try to prove the original proposition directly via the Farkas lemma or the separating hyperplane theorem.

Comment: well, I think you could accept this answer, as proving strong duality for LPs (using Farkas lemma, or otherwise) is really bookwork, something not needed to be repeated here.

Comment: Agree. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a complex problem. It is a straightforward excercise about the dual polytope $P^*$ of $P$ (that every polytope $Q\supset P$ has all its inequalties in $P^*$).

For clarity, assume that $P$ is full-dimensional, and that the origin is in the interior of $P$. Then $b>0$. Hence $A$ can be scaled so that $b=(1,\dots,1)$.

Now $P^*$ is the convex closure of the
rows of $A$, and every valid for $P$ inequality $\langle a',x\rangle\leq \beta$ satisfies $\beta>0$, i.e. is equivalent to   $\beta^{-1}\langle a',x\rangle\leq 1$,
and $\beta^{-1} a'\in P^*$.

Comment: Cool! I see that when the origin is in the interior of the convex hull $P*$ of the rows of the $A$ scaled as you described, called $A'$, $\beta^-1a' = u^T A'$ where $u\ge0$ and $u^T\mathbf 1=1$. But how does one proceed to show the two desired relations from here, especially the second one?

Comment: if your a'x<b' cannot be normalised so that b'=1 then it is not valid (check for x=0).

Comment: Let us say $b'$ or $\beta>0$ so that $b'^{-1}a'^Tx\le1$. How do we argue for the desired relation?

Comment: P* is a polytope, and so each point $a$ (ie an inequality $<a,x>\leq 1$ ) in P*  can be expressed as $\lambda A$ for $\lambda \geq 0$, $\sum \lambda_k=1$. For each point $a$ outside, there will be a separating hyperplane, which, in case of P*, is just $z \in P$ s.t. $<a,z>  >1$.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I knew how to prove your claim that $\frac{a'}{b'}\in P^*$ as I have stated in my first comment. I am asking how you would prove $b'>\lambda b$ for some $\lambda>0$ as posited in the original question. I do not see yet how that is derived from $\frac{a'}{b'}\in P^*$

Comment: there is no $b$ any more. All the b's are now 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120515/discussion-between-hans-and-dima-pasechnik).

Comment: +1 for the great idea! But is it fair to say we have not proved or disproved the original proposition?

Comment: Other than dealing with non-full-dimensional case (just restrict to the affine span of $P$) it looks as if we're done.

Comment: I do not understand what you are claiming. Are you claiming you have proved or disproved the original proposition? It appears that the above answer, which I have upvoted for its illuminating idea, has achieved neither. If you do not agree, could you please present the detailed proof or a counterexample?

Comment: Proved, naturally, and please note I am not oblidged to provide you more details - it's a research maths forum, not undergraduate maths forum.  The whole question ought to be closed as being out of scope.

Comment: perhaps you wonder why there is $\geq$ in $b'\geq\lambda^\top b$, and not $=$. That's because increasing $b'$ for a fixed $a'$ makes the inequality weaker, and indeed there is  minimal $b'$ so that the inequality is still valid (and that's exactly where $b'=\lambda^\top b$ would hold).

Comment: Like I said before, I do very much appreciate your illuminating as evidenced by my upvoting of your answer. However, due to my obtuseness, from the very beginning I am blind to the route leading from your result to the desired relations in the question. The $b′\ge \lambda^Tb$ vs $b′=\lambda^Tb$ is not my worry. I have detailed the current status of the solution in an answer box and stated where I have gotten stuck. Please review and I would very much appreciate it if you would let me know exactly what I have missed.

Comment: Please see my other answer, which gives a full answer to your question (yes, the inequality holds, but it's not easy to prove).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proof per se but for detailed discussion with Dima Pasechnik. It is too long for the comment section.

---

Suppose $P$ is bounded and not a singleton. The original proposition does not stipulate $0\in $ interior of $P$.

I transcribe Dima Pasechnik's answer in detail as follows. We pick an interior point $x_0$ of $P$, i.e., $Ax_0<b$. Let $y:=x-x_0$.
\begin{align}
Ay&\le b-Ax_0=:\beta \\
\implies a'y&\le b'-a'x_0=:\beta'
\end{align}
where vector $\beta>0$ and scalar $\beta'>0$. Writing the matrices in the entry form so as to be clear, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_j\frac{A_{ij}}{\beta_i}y_j&\le1 \\
\implies \sum_j\frac{a'_j}{\beta'}y_j&\le1.
\end{align}
By Farkas' lemma or the separating hyperplane theorem, $\forall j$, $\frac{a'_j}{\beta'}$ is a convex combination of $\Big\{\frac{A_{ij}}{\beta_i}\Big\}_i$, or $\exists u\in R^n$ such that $u_i\ge0\, \forall i, \sum_iu_i=1$ and
$$\frac{a'_j}{\beta'}=\sum_i u_i\frac{A_{ij}}{\beta_i}$$
or
$$\frac{a'_j}{b'-\sum_ja'_jx_{0,j}}=\sum_i u_i\frac{A_{ij}}{b_i-\sum_jA_{ij}x_{0,j}} \tag1$$
$\forall j$.

Now, the question is how one derives from Equation (1) the desired inequalities in the question, i.e.
\begin{align}
a'_j &= \sum_i\lambda_i A_{ij} \quad\forall j, \\
b' &\geq \sum_i\lambda_i b_i  \tag2
\end{align}
for some $\lambda_i\ge0, \forall i$ (without requiring $\sum_i\lambda_i=1$).

Note that the convex combination in (1) is for the ratio as opposed to for the numerator and denominator separately. Moreover, the denominator of (1) involves $A, a', x_0$ rather than just $b$ and $b'$, while (2) especial the second relation $b'\ge \lambda^Tb$ is independent of $A, a'$ especially $x_0$.

---

I doubt you can derive (2) from (1) directly without other conditions.

If we define as Dima Pasechnik suggests
$$\lambda_i := u_i\frac{\beta'}{\beta_i},$$
we obtain the equation above Inequality (2) which I had obtained  without the normalization or the dual polytope concept, as well as for $x_0=0$ which makes $\beta=b$ and $\beta'=b'$ the equality version of (2). However, it is not clear how we could arrive at Inequality (2) under the general condition where both $\beta$ and $\beta'$ depend on $x_0$ which is the ultimate question I am after, since $\beta$ and $\beta'$ depend on $x_0$ while $b$ and $b'$ do not.

Comment: how about setting $\lambda_i=u_i/b_{1,i}$ ? We're playing a bit carelessly with signs of $b_{1,k}$ here, but assuming $b_1>0$ it all looks fine.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: I discussed your suggestion in my answer above. It is not clear to me this works in general. Also I have improved my symbols.